# Is it possible to apply your main domain's SSL cert to subdomains in Plesk?

Tags: ssl, subdomain, plesk

I have an SSL cert working on my main domain but I cannot get it working on subdomains off the main domain.  The hosting vendor is now telling me I need to buy a wildcard SSL.  Wish they had been honest with me while I was researching the windows host product.  They assured me in multiple conversations the SSL would work with all Sub Domains off the main domain I applied the SSL cert to.

They said only if I had a completely different domain in addition to the first one would I need to purchase a second SSL or SSL package.

This is the first I've heard of this wild card domain thing.
So I guess I either need to purchase that or go to letsencrypt for every subdomain.

Is anyone able to just apply your SSL to all subdomains under the main domain you have applied your cert to?

Total newbie here in working with web host environment.

I also noticed you could go to SSL/TLS Certificats
[image]

But when you go to that page for the subdomain's site, it already has the main domain's SSL cert listed along with an upload button.

Comment: You do need to account for multiple domains, either through a wildcard SSL cert, or by listing each domain as a subject alternative name in a single cert, or by using multiple certs, or some combination. The domains in the subject alternative names do not have to be related. The certificate for this very page is perfect example, take a look at it. It has wildcard domains and unrelated domains. I believe letsencrypt supports all these options but I'm not a letsencrypt expert.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - Oh it looks like it came from letsencrypt too.

Comment: Well it looks like Let's Encrypt does not recommend using their SSL certs in a shared hosting scenario like GoDaddy.  Well I will research and provide updates.  I am good for nothing if not researching this kind of crud. https://letsencrypt.org/docs/godaddy/

Comment: Here is something written for using Let's Encrypt on GoDaddy.
Trying to make siense of this now.
https://ae.godaddy.com/help/install-a-lets-encrypt-certificate-on-your-linux-hosting-account-28023

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on **Reissue Certificate**

[image]

and click on **Install**

[image]

and select all subdomain names (under Available Domain Aliases)

[image]

and click **Get it free**

I hope this helps.